# Поиск в excel-файле

Tags: c#, excel, office-interop

Есть excel-файл, в нем два столбца А и В.
Из программы на C# мне нужно организовать поиск значения в столбце А, и вернуть в программу рядом стоящее значение из столбца В.
Т.е. в программе задаю искать 3, а в программу возвращается 13.

Как лучше это организовать? Через Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel? Или лучше не использовать excel-файл, а поместить данные куда-то ещё? БД запонять не очень хочется, т.к. данные будут меняться и придется каждый раз обновлять, возни много.

```
А     В
1     11
2     12
3     13
4     14
5     15
```

Comment: Есть вариант csv

Comment: @nick_n_a, а искать как?

Comment: Вариант 1 sql,  Вариант 2 - `DataTable`,  Вариант 3 `Dictionary<>` или `List<string>`

Comment: @nick_n_a, разобралась, спасибо за наводку про csv

Answer (score 0):

Еще можно использовать LinqToExcel. Для его работы необходим только установленный Microsoft Access Database Engine. Соответственно для него не нужен установленный Excel.

Answer (score 0):

В вашем случае, самым простым способом добиться желаемого результата будет использование библиотеки [ExcelDataReader](https://github.com/ExcelDataReader/ExcelDataReader). Ниже показан пример, как можно реализовать  поиск.

Само решение можно разбить на две части.

1. Первое, читаем данные из `Excel` и представляем их в виде коллекции, реализующей `IEnumerable<T>`. Это необходимо для того, что бы была возможность использовать `Linq`.

   ```
   var stream = File.Open(@"C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\MyExcel.xlsx", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

   var excelReader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(stream);
   var dataSet = excelReader.AsDataSet();

   var enumerable = result.Tables[0].AsEnumerable();
   ```
2. Фильтрация.

   ```
   var result = from item in enumerable
                where item[0].ToString() == "3"
                select item[1].ToString();

   foreach (var i in result)
   {
       Console.WriteLine(i);
   }
   ```